# 240V AC to 30ish DC @ 40-200ish A

Tags: dc, power-electronics, amperage, arc

Alright so I will start with what I am trying to accomplish:

So I want to build an power inverter based welder. I see these commonly in all new Lincoln and Miller welders. These all can change the amperage in increments of 1A. From what I have found these are "SMPS" and operate around 30kHz. 
I'm trying to make a MIG, TIG, and Stick rig. I get that part of it after I can generate the high amperage. It seems simple once I figure how to do that. If it maters the max draw on the main should be around 40A. [Here](http://www.trade-equip.co.uk/blog/?p=169) Is what I have been looking at for the information.

So how would one do this. Ask anything else to clear it up.

Comment: 250A at 46VDC = 11.5kW or, from a 240V AC supply that's a current of  48A plus add another 10% for inefficiencies and incidentally, those inefficiences are given of as heat so that's about 1.2kW in heat. Does this mean anything to you?

Comment: I do not want to discourage you at all. But this seems like a pretty difficult project. Are you sure you want to start with this? Do you have the equipment you need to test your supply, or will you be making and buying such equipment? Are you somewhat familiar with the concept of power factor? In order to design an AC to DC converter that consumes 35A, you will have to make sure you present a well-behaved impedance characteristic to the utility. The block diagram you linked to competely glosses over that part of the power conversion.

Comment: What are you going to weld? Whole tanks? Maybe start with something at the lower end

Comment: The input current, power and losses will not be a simple calculation based on output voltage and current. The output voltage specified for a welder is the open circuit voltage and the output current is the maximum current after an arc has been established. The sizing of the rectifiers and inverter will also be based on the welder's duty cycle rating. The current and voltage control will need to be designed to keep the output within safe limits. I would expect that some kind of warning would need to be provided to help the operator to stay within duty cycle limits.

Comment: Ok, if I go down to 200amps max ouput. Would that help some? Also the voltage on the ouput I guess doesn't matter as much as I thought. I'm just basing this on what Miller welders say in Ag Shop. On the topic of SMPS, how would amperage be adjusted on the output

Comment: You are absurdly over-reaching.  A 200A welder is roughly a 3kW isolated switching power-supply, which is an incredibly complex undertaking, particularly as it requires a number of very high-current custom components.  Even a 3W (notice the 1000-fold reduction in power) mains-input switching power-supply is a difficult and dangerous thing to develop from scratch.   If you're interested in how welders work, buy broken ones and fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an outline of how you might go about a project like this. To do this safely and successfully, you need quite a bit of knowledge and experience.

Develop complete specifications

Read the complete specifications for the example product and understand all of the specifications.

Input voltage, 1 or 3 phase, frequency

Output open-circuit voltage, operating current, operating voltage

Maximum output power: highest arc voltage X arc current

Duty cycle definition: Is it time drawing an arc divided by total operating time?

Average output power

Operator adjustments and selections: Read the operator’s manual for the example product and understand all of the adjustments and selections that the operator can make.

These are the sections and major components that need to be designed or selected:

1. Input Circuit Breaker
2. Rectifier: Rectifier module, heat sink, possibly a cooling fan
3. Filter: Capacitor or capacitor bank and possibly a charge current limiting mechanism
4. Inverter power unit: IGBT transistor module, heat sink, cooling fan
5. Transformer: Special 30 kHz transformer, probably a custom-made item in the example product, might need it’s own cooling fan
6. Rectifier: 30 kHz Rectifier module, heat sink, possibly a cooling fan
7. Inductor: Filters 30 kHz rectifier output and limits rapid output current changes
8. DC voltage and current transducers
9. PWM current and voltage control unit: This receives the operator selection and adjustment inputs, monitors the output voltage and current, compares the actual voltage and current with the operator selections and settings and the design limits, monitors the duty cycle, possibly monitors some internal temperatures and sends pulse width modulation (PWM) gate signals to the inverter to control the welder. It could probably be a single-board microcontroller that you would program to perform the required functions.
10. IGBT Gate signal driver: This receives signals from the control unit and provides isolated signals to the IGBT gates.
11. Operator input devices and miscellaneous items.

Comment: So the PWM will control the amps and the volts? Your explanation make perfect sense till there. Thanks

Comment: Yes. The PWM directly sets the effective voltage of the inverter voltage waveform and indirectly controls the current by monitoring the current and adjusting the voltage to make the current increase or decrease as required. The operator can set a value for either the output voltage or current. The parameter that is not set is allowed to vary within some limits. That is the sort of thing that should be explained in the operator manual.